# Can I run a custom maven plugin after the maven-release plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

Is it possible to call another maven plugin after the maven release plugin completes?  I want to notify another service we have that a release has been made (with information about the code itself, specifically about classes that have a certain annotation).

I will need to create the custom plugin, which will call my service, but want to know how I can hook this into the deployment phase after the deployment of the release artifact has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify it in the command line, goals will be executed in the order they are declared:

```
mvn release:perform my-plugin:my-goal
```

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/plugin-info.html) mentions all the goals that are available for this plugin.

The last goal provided by maven is deploy, and `Maven Release Plugin` references this to perform the `release:stage` execution.

If you want to execute another maven plugin after the maven release you just need to specify it in the POM file after the maven release plugin and reference its execution to the `deploy goal`